# Can I turn off PyCharm autocomplete for a specific class

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm, type-hinting, pydantic

**Is there a way in Python on in Pycharm to indicate that I don't want the type hint of a specific class to be displayed to the user in the autocomplete window?**

I have a class `Result` that may contain either a string, e.g. `1+2` or an instance of another class `Exercise`. The `Exercise` class contains 2 numbers and can generate an exercise string from them.

`Result` class uses Pydantic *(also see footnote)* to validate the input as a str or `Exercise` types, so I must declare a Union of types:

```
exercise: Union[str, Exercise]
```

At the end I want future users of my code to get autocomplete suggestions that treat the property `exercise` as `str` only and ignore the `Exercise` type.

In the screenshot you can see that the autocomplete window has suggestions for both `str` and `Exercise` types.

[image: autocomplete suggests properties and methods for both str and Exercise]

So my question is: **Is there a way in Python on in Pycharm to indicate that I don't want the type hint of a specific class to be displayed to the user in the autocomplete window?**

---

**Footnote**

- In the example I am using Pydantic to define `Exercise(BaseModel)` to make my point, but you can use the other definition of `Exercise`.

---

**Code**

```
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel


#
# class Exercise:
#     def __init__(self, num1: int, num2: int):
#         self.num1: int = num1
#         self.num2: int = num2
#
#     def convert_to_str(self) -> str:
#         return f'{self.num1} + {self.num2}'


class Exercise(BaseModel):
    num1: int
    num2: int

    def convert_to_str(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.num1} + {self.num2}'


class Result(BaseModel):
    exercise: Union[str, Exercise]

    def convert_to_str(self):
        if isinstance(self.exercise, Exercise):
            self.exercise = self.exercise.convert_to_str()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exercise_example: Exercise = Exercise(num1=1, num2=2)
    result1: Result = Result(exercise=exercise_example)

    print(result1.exercise)
    result1.convert_to_str()
    print(result1.exercise)

    print(result1.exercise.split('+'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you show seems odd to me because it could be argued that avoiding `str` and using just `Exercise` could provide a better object oriented approach.

Assuming that you actually want an `exercise: str` field but you want a way to initialize it by converting an `Exercise` instance to `str`, you could use a [`@validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/):

```python
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Exercise(BaseModel):
    num1: int
    num2: int

    def convert_to_str(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.num1} + {self.num2}'


class Result(BaseModel):
    exercise: str

    @validator("exercise", pre=True)
    def _convert_exercise(cls, exercise: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(exercise, Exercise):
            return exercise.convert_to_str()
        return exercise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exercise_example: Exercise = Exercise(num1=1, num2=2)
    result1: Result = Result(exercise=exercise_example)

    print(result1.exercise)
    print(result1.exercise.split('+'))
```

Output:

```
1 + 2
['1 ', ' 2']
```

That validator will only convert `Exercise` instances to `str`. Instances of other classes will remain intact. `pre=True` will cause this validator to be called prior to other validations. The `exercise` field will be a `str` and not a `Union` and any IDE should only show you autocomplete suggestions for `str`.

Comment: Thanks Hernan. Your solution is the path I will most likely use. I wanted to avoid using validators in order to minimize the extra code. I have multiple fields like this that can return different types. I am still hoping this can be solved using some Python/PyCharm flagging of exercise.

Comment: In my case, I am going to do the conversion only later, as a post processing of the complete BaseModel. This means that the field `exercise` must accept `Exercise`. The use of a validator in this case will cannot return `Exercise` unless it is defined in the `Union[]` as in my question code example

Comment: I also opened a question for PyCharm support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7040283146642-How-to-hide-PyCharm-autocomplete-for-specific-class

Comment: This is the official reply I got on the question from PyCharm team: "This is a limitation of PyCharm type checker, unfortunately. Here's a request to improve it https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24834/Support-stricter-handling-of-typingUnion-types-similar-to-that-in-mypy"